# issues with select statement for recordset

Tags: php, sql

I am doing a project with dreamweaver and I ran into a hitch with my select statement.
I have this

```
 SELECT *
    FROM client, `statement`
    WHERE client.client_id = `statement`.client_id
```

when I execute this it selects everybody in the database. So I want to add another WHERE statement to this query, this time one that compares the client.username with the session variable "MM_Username".

So I am looking at something like this

```
SELECT *
    FROM client, `statement`
    WHERE client.client_id = `statement`.client_id  AND WHERE client.username = '$_SESSION['MM_Username']'
```

The session PHP code is as follows

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

// *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
  $isValid = False; 

  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "myflog.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be another `WHERE`; you connect your conditions with `AND`:

```
WHERE client.client_id = `statement`.client_id AND client.username = '$_SESSION['MM_Username']'
```

For further information, please refer to the SQL syntax definition of the SQL engine you are using for the syntax of `SELECT` queries.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM client, `statement` WHERE client.client_id = `statement`.client_id AND client.username = '$_SESSION['MM_Username']';

or
$user_name=$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
SELECT *
FROM client c, statement s WHERE c.client_id = s.client_id AND c.username = '$user_name';

Try this query